# Karma-Coverage is failing to run

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, karma-runner

I am trying to get unit test coverage for an angular.js project. I am using Karm and the Karma-coverage tool via config. I am not seeing any output at all that the coverage reporter is running

`DEBUG [preprocessor.coverage]: Processing "/home/ <blah>"`

The Preprocessoror is running, I am seeing it in the console. Likewise, I see the junit reporter create a file after running the tests:

`DEBUG [reporter.junit]: JUnit results written to...`

I see nothing about code coverage and can't find a file anywhere. Here's the config:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
    basePath : '../',
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],

    preprocessors : {
       'app/js/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    files : [
      'app/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
      'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
      'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
      'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/js/**/*.js',
      'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    plugins : [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-coverage'       
        ],
    coverageReporter : {
           type : 'text',
           file : 'coverage.txt'
    },
    junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
    }
})}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same problem and haven't been able to dig up anything on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by:

Removing the node_modules and reinstalling the prerequisites. I had an issue with the karma-coverage plugin not installing due to sudo requirements using node install. Installing via `sudo npm install` fixed the issue.

I also removed all the fluff from my karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
    basePath : '../',
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files : [
        'app/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
        'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
        'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
        'app/lib/underscore.js',
        'app/lib/**/*.js',
        'app/js/**/*.js',
        'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ],

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    preprocessors : {
       'app/js/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    }
})}
```